# Retrieve all text of an element including its child in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree, xml.etree

i wrote a code to find text in specific tags in an xml. It works fine for tags without a child tag.

```
For e.g. 1 <a>ajsaka</a>. it works fine for this. 

e.g. 2 But if there is an instance of <b>ahsjd<c>jjiij</c>aa</b>.
```

It doesnt work. I want all the content in a tag including its child element text. I want it to print ahsjdjjiijaa, but instead it prints only ahsjd. Here is my code so far.

Here is the input file.

```
<level>
<ex>
<nt>[edit <topic-ref link-text="short-title"
topic-id="13629">address</topic-ref>],</nt>
<nt>[edit routing-instances <var>routing-instance-name</var
    > <topic-ref link-text="short-title" topic-id="13629">address-
assignment</topic-ref
>]</nt>
</ex>
   <exam>
   </exam>
</level>

from lxml import etree
doc=etree.parse('C:/xx/bb.xml')
root=doc.getroot()
node=root.find('level')
count=len(node.getchildren())
print (count)
for elem in root.findall('level/ex/nt'):
    print (elem.text)
```

How do i get it?

Comment: here are no `level` tags within your input xml. Extend your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read your file as string, then concatinate all text between tags

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
text = open('C:/xx/bb.xml').read()
''.join(ET.fromstring(text).itertext())
```

Output :

```
'ahsjdjjiijaa'
```

Comment: it works when i want all content in my file as a string? isnt. Sorry, if i am wrong. I want only content inside a particular tag even if it has child tags inside.

Comment: for elem in root.findall('hierarchy-level/example/statement'):
 print ("".join([x for x in elem.itertext()]))

it worked. Thanks. Now i understand.