# Get text from xml that is behind an extra tag in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I was trying to extract the text between tags from an .xml file but I found that some parts of the text has an `<italic>` tag that cuts the text after that and makes it impossible for me to get it. The document has multiple blocks of `<p>` and `<s>` tags and `<s>` are always inside `<p>`. Here is an example:

```xml
<p id="0"><s id="0" corresp="992">Bla, Bla, Bla... <italics>italic</italics> bla, bla, bla.</s></p>
```

When I get to the element `<s>` the text output is `'Bla, Bla, Bla...'` and from there I can get the element 'italics' which output text is `'italic'` but I can't access the text  `'bla, bla, bla.'`.

This is the code that I'm using to get the text:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

document= ET.parse('file.xml')
for a in document.findall('p'):
   paragraph = a.findall('s')
   for a in paragraph:
       print(a.text)
```

The only way around that I found is to manually delete the `<italics>` tags but I don't think thats a good way to do it, how can I do it better?

The expected output should be `'Bla, Bla, Bla...italic bla, bla, bla.'`

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your exact expected output?

Comment: The text immediately after the `</italics>` end tag is the `tail` of that element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail.

Comment: To get the expected output, use `itertext()`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19369901/407651. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44699404/407651

Comment: You can also use lxml instead of ElementTree; it will be a tad shorter.

Comment: Thx for your responses, @mzjn comment worked like a charm. Can you give me some guidance on the use of lxml? In fact this code is just a part of the actual script, the actual code has 6 for X in X.findall('XXXX') because I dont know other way to do it.

Comment: If you want help with using lxml, please ask a new question.